# Link detect and replace the other,in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello
  I wonder how Replace automatically links on my site
that start with:

http://site.com/00000/

to:

http://site.com/11111/

detects> replaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 [attribute "starts with" selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) help you there (and jQuery supports them on all of the browsers it supports — with native features if possible, for speed). Then just use an `each` loop and update the `href` property of the raw `a` element:

```
$("a[href^='http://site.com/00000/']").each(function() {
    this.href = "http://site.com/11111/" + this.href.substring(21);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a small error there (in this particular case, the attribute value being matched must be in quotes); fixed.

Comment: +1 Nice and concise, didn't think about using a selector directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuerys `.attr()` method. You don't need to explicitly invoke `.each()`, jQuery will take care of you if your selector hits multiple nodes. Since version 1.4.1, `.attr()` like many other setters, takes a function as argument. This function gets the **index** and the actual **value** passed in. Whatever you return from this callback is going to be the new value.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('a').attr('href', function(_, href) {
         return href.replace('246619', '262257');
    });
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qR2NU/

**Reference**: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var urlContain = new RegExp('Detect Value Here');
        $('a').each(function () { 
            var href = this.getAttribute('href').replace(urlContain, 'Replacement here');
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through every link on the page that has a `href` attribute once the DOM has loaded and performs the required replace:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href !== undefined) {
      href = href.replace(/246619/g, '262257');
    }
    $(this).attr('href', href);
  });
});
```

The above relies on jQuery but judging by the tags you used for your question, you are already using it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
$("a[href^=http://site.com/00000/]").each(function() {
  this.href = "http://site.com/11111/" + this.href.substr("http://site.com/00000/".length");
});
```